# Laravel Debugging $request from Mobile App Frontend

Tags: laravel

can anyone suggest a more elaborate way to debug incoming variables from Request in my Laravel controller that is being passed from a Mobile App? (Ex. Live Debugging as request is sent from mobile app)

Currently I'm dumping variables into a log file, and reviewing those logs.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may use [Laravel Dump Server](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-dump-server).

Comment: Not sure which version of Laravel you're using, but [Telescope](https://github.com/laravel/telescope) is a game-changer for me.

Comment: Thanks all! I took a look at Dump Server, and it's does the job perfectly, I'll have to play around with Telescope to compare the two. I'm currently using 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

use laarvel dump server package

```
composer require --dev beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
```

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-dump-server

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, definitely alot more convenient than what I was doing!